# Programmatic way of checking what validations failed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Is there a way to retrieve failed validations without checking the error message?

If I have a model with `validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true`, how can I check if determine what validation failed(was it uniqueness or was it presence?)  without doing stuff like:

```
if error_message == "can't be blank"
  # handle presence validation
elsif error_message = "has already been taken"
  # handle uniqueness validation
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a relatively new method that let you do just that, it's not documented anywhere as far as I know and I just stumbled on it while reading the source code, it's the `#added?` method:

```
person.errors.added? :name, :blank
```

Here's the original pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3369

Answer (score 2):

[ActiveModel::Errors](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.10/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb) is nothing more than a dumb hash, mapping attributes names to human-readable error messages. The validations (eg. [the presence one](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.10/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb)) directly add their messages to the `errors` object without specifying where they came from.

In short, there doesn't seem to be an official way of doing this.

Comment: after some more research I eventually reached the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can Haz all your errors in the errors method. Try this on an saved unvalid record :

`record.errors.map {|a| "#{a.first} => #{a.last}"}`

Comment: record.errors returns and ActiveModel::Errors objects which contains the error messages. I wanted to know if there is another way to check what validations failed other than comparing error messages.

Comment: Well you get a precise list of the failed validation when you do the above, so you don't need to compare error_messages, just extract them from the list. but maybee I misunderstood the question

Comment: I get something like this :@messages={:name=>["can't be blank"], :library_version=>["can't be blank"], :language=>["can't be blank"]}>. To narrow it down to the exact validations(uniqueness or presence) I have to check the error messages.

Comment: I see better now, thanks to Garret's answer (it's easy to overlook the  question's detail)... And yes it is a dumb hash so there's not much to do about it. Eventually use a state machine like state_machine to deal with complex validations and before/after hooks. But it might be overkill here....